# PHP: update variables on while statements

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to the PHP world! Currently practicing MySQL and PHP alone

I want to update my `<p>` content when my query is completed. But seems like my `$name` only shows the previous value:

```
$query = $_GET['query'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM wordList WHERE word = '$query'");
$name = ''; // my variable
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $name == $row['word']; // not working
}
```

And I am not getting the actual data I want in my HTML:

```
<p>My name is: <?php echo $name; ?></p>
```

But getting:

> My name is:

Thanks

Comment: Firstly, you need to escape your `$query` variable, and concat the string with `.`. So it should be `word = ' . $query . '");`. 

Also, you're comparing name, not assigning. You need to assign it with a single `=`.

Comment: @BillyPurvis, thanks man. Done

Comment: Did it work? I'll make it the answer haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using only one equal to symbol `=` instead of `==`.

```
$name = $row['word'];
```

Comment: Worked like charm Thanks